# Custom module: Access denied (ACL Problem)

Tags: module, magento-1, acl

I created a module, and it works perfectly; however, I hit a wall. When I'm logged in as admin, everthing is good. I added this in the acl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <erp translate="title" module="firtal_deadstock">
            <title>ERP</title>
            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
            <children>
                <stock_management module="firtal_deadstock">
                                <title>Stock Management</title>
                                <children>
                                    <firtal_deadstock>
                                        <title><![CDATA[Firtal Stock Analysis]]></title>
                                        <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                                        <action>adminhtml/deadstock</action>
                                    </firtal_deadstock>
                                </children>
                </stock_management>
            </children>
        </erp>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources> 
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <firtal_deadstock translate="title">
                                        <title>Firtal Stock Analysis settings</title>
                                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                    </firtal_deadstock>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <erp module="firtal_deadstock">
                        <children>
                            <stock_management module="firtal_deadstock">
                                <children>
                                    <firtal_deadstock translate="title" module="firtal_deadstock">
                                        <title>Firtal Stock Analysis</title>
                                    </firtal_deadstock>
                                </children>
                            </stock_management>
                        </children>
                    </erp>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

But if I grant the permission to a role and login as a user with that role, they do see the menu point (not the config, but the actual menu point), but if I press it, I get an Access Denied error:

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have a hunch you have in your admin controller a method called `_isAllowed`.
If that's true, I think it returns the wrong thing.
It should look like this:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('erp/stock_management/firtal_deadstock');  
    //or at least
    //return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('erp/stock_management');  

}
```

Comment: DUH! That was it. I actually tried to add a _isAllowed(), but that gave me a 503. I was working on a live server, so I couldn't see the exception data. Obviously it was because I was redeclaring it as I forgot I declared it in the middle of the class. Thanks a bunch, have a great weekend!

Comment: or you can also write : protected function _isAllowed() {
      return true;
    }

Comment: But that will make it available for every admin. Even if he should not have access to it.